# Unhandled rejection MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

problems occured when I am trying to connect mlab's online mangodb server.Anyone can give me some advice? Here is my controller code and error pictures.

The error log said I didn't handle the rejection but I have checked my code with some mongoose documents and can't find the mistakes. xD
(I also cheked my db name and pw)

[the controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6XMV.png)

[the error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQN87.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be error with your connection string also use have not handle error cases in code i.e try {}  catch{} block is missing hence the error stating that unhandled rejection .

Please check your connection string once.

Comment: You mean database url? Ok, I will check it again.